# When to use controllers when using components with Ember

Tags: ember.js, controller, web-component

In the latest (1.10+) versions of Ember there seems to be a trend to make use of components instead of controllers and views.

[The wisdom seems to be](https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97):
"Only use controllers at the top-level for receiving data from the route, and use Ember.Controller instead of Ember.ArrayController or Ember.ObjectController"

This makes some sense to me as it's cool to create reusable components, but there are some scenarios where it is unclear to me what the appropriate approach is.

Say we have a component which represents a row in a table, something like this:

```
# entry-row.js component
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'tr',

  actions: {
    toggleResolving: function() {
      this.toggleProperty('resolving');
    }
  },

  isChecked: function() {
    return this.get('resolving');
  }.property('resolving')
});

# entry-row.hbs template
<td {{action "toggleResolving"}}>{{entry.name}}</td>
<td>{{entry.currency.symbol}}{{entry.amount}}</td>
<td>{{entry.date}}</td>
<td class="bs-checkbox">{{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked class="toggle"}}</td>
```

To form a table, many of the same component are used. That's great. If there is some non-persistent state which applies only to that row then that can belong to the component and be changed there. Something like:

```
actions: {
    toggleResolving: function() {
      this.toggleProperty('resolving');
    }
  }
```

But say that my `resolving` property is also useful outside the component. In this case, I wish to be able to mark several rows for resolution and then perform some action on them collectively. I believe that before the switch to components, I would have defined the `resolving` property on the Controller and made use of that controller wherever I needed the model + state.

Should I still be putting this on the controller?

Comment: Have another component that wraps all the rows to manage state outside the rows.

Comment: @blessenm That was my initial thought also, but say that I then want something completely disconnected in my application which makes use of this. For example, a status box somewhere (probably a component itself) else that lists the current rows marked for resolution.

Comment: May be using an event bus would help to communicate between separate components. http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2015/04/27/event-bus/ You could also use services and inject them into it component.

Comment: That sounds like a very complicated way of achieving what was previously very simple. Surely that can't be the intended replacement?

Comment: Well communication between sibling components is a problem being discussed a lot. There are many techniques - bindings, services, event bus. But there is no consensus on whats the way to go. Here some links that may give u some more info. http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/communication-between-components/7353 http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/getting-ember-components-to-respond-to-actions/

Answer (score 0):

Besides using an outer component, another option is to put properties on the model. You can also share common actions with mixins.